# PDF unexpectedly produced many pages

Tags: jasper-reports

When I preview a report in iReport, it is formatted as expected.

However, that PDF Copy(File) has many pages. Single copy sometimes has many pages.

Thank you.

Comment: Post a minimal example JRXML that shows the problem. Also, if you can show us what you are getting and what you expect to get, that would be helpful. Post images using http://imgur.com/.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have detail section that spreads as you miltirow dataset. As long as you have many rows from data source - you document extends several pages to put all the data.

Thanks,
Arty